# jail-monkey isJailBroken() method returns false for Android emulator after React-Native upgrade

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator, jailbreak, rooted-device

We are currently facing an issue with the jailbreak detection feature in the jail-monkey library after upgrading our React Native application to a newer version. Prior to the upgrade, the isJailBroken() method was functioning correctly and returning true as expected when running the app on both Android emulator and iOS simulator.

However, post the React Native upgrade, the isJailBroken() method now consistently returns false when the app is run on the emulator.

Additional Information:

React Native Version: 0.72.5
jail-monkey Version: 2.8.0
Emulator: Android Studio Emulator

We have thoroughly checked for changes in the React Native upgrade documentation and the jail-monkey release notes but haven't found any relevant information. Any guidance or insights into resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.